# Proving invertibility of a matrix from given equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given is the vector $e_{1} = (1,0,0)^T \in \mathbb{R}^{3} $ and a $3x3$ Matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3x3}$, so that the vectors $$Ae_1, A^2e_1,A^3e_1$$
are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3} $.

**Question:** Prove that A is invertible.

My idea was to write the Matrix A as:
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
and calculate $A^2$ and $A^3$. Then the the vectors of $A, A^2, A^3$ given by the first element of each column have to be independent (since $Ae_1, A^2e_1,A^3e_1$ are a basis). This leads to a set of equations, from which follows that the rows of A have to be independent, so $det(A)\ne 0$, thus A is invertible. Is there any easier/quicker way of solving this?

Thank you!

Comment: Notice that the three vectors $A^ke_1$ are all in the image of $A$, so $A$ is surjective, and thus invertible

Comment: In general it's good to avoid writing out the entries of a matrix when you can avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $\mathcal{B} = \{\vec{v}_1 , \vec{v}_2 , \ldots , \vec{v}_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the matrix $[\mathcal{B}]$ that has its columns the vectors of $\mathcal{B}$, is invertible.

Taking $\mathcal{B} = \{Ae_1, A^2e_1, A^3e_1\}$, we have that

$$[\mathcal{B}] = A \cdot [\{e_1,Ae_1,A^2e_1\}]$$

is invertible, so $A$ itself is invertible. Notice that this also proves that $\{e_1 , Ae_1, A^2e_1\}$ is a basis, that is, is a linearly independent set of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Also notice that the dimension of the space was not needed, so the same conclusion holds if $\{ Ae_1 , A^2 e_1 , \ldots, A^ne_1\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (the vector $v = Ae_1$ is called $A$-cyclic in this case).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! That is a much faster and elegant solution!